# 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I'm getting massage in this format : 
'02 01 01 21 03 01 02 00 01 01 20 b6 01 0 26 cd 00 03 30 63 a4 22 01'

And need to parse this, convert to hex, slice it and convert back, but not sure If I'm doing this right. I got this error from the title of the question because "buf" is apparently a list, not a string. Actually, I'm not sure if I'm doing this conversion right at all?

```
def parse_code(msg):
    buf = (hashlib.sha256(bytearray.fromhex(msg)).hexdigest())
    buf = int(buf, 16)

    datetime_now = datetime.now()
    log_date = datetime_now.isoformat()

    try:
        prepare_adress = buf[16:22]
        hex_adress = int(prepare_adress, 16)
        new_adress =hex_adress + 0x200
        adress = hex(new_adress).upper()
        id = buf[4:]
        prepare_usage = buf[1:2]
        hex_usage = int(prepare_usage, 16)
        new_usage =hex_usage + 0x200
        usage = hex(new_usage).upper()
        time_a = int(time())
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
```

Any idea how to handle the error and maybe some advice for a better approach to convert a message to hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing first : do yourself a favour and get rid of this braindead try/except clause which is totally useless and prevents you from getting the full traceback when something goes wrong (the traceback is really helpful for debugging so you never want to lose it). As a general rule, only catch exception you can properly handle, else let them propagate.

Now wrt/ your current error the cause is obvious - here:

```
buf = int(buf, 16)
```

you make `buf` an integer. Then here:

```
prepare_adress = buf[16:22]
```

you try to slice it - which makes no sense, an integer a scalar, not a sequence, and cannot be subscripted nor sliced nor iterated in any way.